# regex - Clarity about Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, regular-language

I just would like some clarity about regular expressions:

( Note: Σ={a,b} )
If a question asks for `a string that contains an even number of a's` does this mean 0 a's fits in, and so does an empty string? Does `bbbbb` have an even number of a's?

Does `aaaaa` have b's which are a multiple of 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero), zero is *even*, so `bbbbb` has an even number of `a`'s.

For the second question *0* is a multiple of all the numbers, so *0* is multiple of *3* (specifically 0 * 3), then `aaaaa` has a number of `b`'s which is a multiple of *3*.

Answer (score 0):

`0` counts as an even number. `bbbbb` has 0 a's, hence and even number of a's. `aaaaa` has 0 b's, and 0 is a multiple of 3. Although this doesn't really have much to do about regular expressions itself.